# Side job as trainer

Tags: contracts, training

I'm currently working in a big IT consultancy company. As part of my job I'm training people from my company in some of the newest technology in the market.

I was wondering if it's possible for me to make the same kind of courses in other companies by myself. That would be an opportunity for me to get some good experience (nice to have in the CV) and earn some money.

Do you think is this ok? Should I notify my company before doing any movement? What if they say no or they say that we can sell this as a company service?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Depends on the terms of your employment and any non-compete clauses it might contains as well as the culture of your organisation. Impossible to answer from the web.

Comment: @AndrewBerry  it's similar, but in my case, the thing I'm offering is done within the company (although it can change if needed)

Comment: Did you read the answers @ZanattMan? They all apply correctly to this question, mainly in regards to you have to be careful on competing clauses.

Comment: What does your contract say ?

Answer (score 1):

Several things to consider, each having an impact on the answer.

- Is the technology you are teaching proprietary to your company? If so, you cannot moonlight.
- Is the training package being put together from what you have done on company time? If so, you cannot moonlight.
- Does the company offer training services in other areas (but not this one) and do you have a non-compete? If so, you cannot moonlight.

Basically, the best option is to put together a brief marketing strategy for this training and present it to your boss, offering them first refusal. If they say they are not interested, then you should be fine to crack on with some side income (provided the other conditions are all clear).